# Setting default value in options angular

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to set a default selected value in a `select` statement:

```
<p ng-repeat="something in somethings">
    <select data-ng-options="key as value for (key , value) in values[$index]" ></select>
</p>
```

My `values` look like this:

```
[{1:2,2:3},{1:2,2:3},{1:2,2:3}]
```

Note that `$index` is outside iteration loop's index.

Now imagine I want to select option `1` in 1st iteration of `$index` and `2` in second iteration etc.

How to achieve the same?

Comment: please elaborate your question ? `"I want to select option 1 in 1st iteration of $index and 2.."`, ? didn't get this line. you want select 2 or option 2?. please elaborate

Answer (score 0):

you need **ng-model** angular attribute on your select control to set default item. for exmaple:

```
 <p ng-repeat="something in somethings">
    <select ng-model="something.defaultValue" data-ng-options="key as value for (key , value) in values[$index]" ></select>
</p>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, a good answer also demonstrates the solution.  Please [edit] to provide example code to show what you mean. Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use Ng-model and assign it a value, to set default option in dropdown,

```
<p ng-repeat="something in somethings">
    <select ng-model="defaultValues[$index]" data-ng-options="key as value for (key , value) in values[$index]" ></select>
</p>
```

**Script.js**

```
defaultValues[0] = 'Default Value'
```